# How to get buttons side by side?

Tags: html, css

So I have two social buttons as follows:

```
<span class="zocial facebook"><a href="#">Share on Facebook/a></span>
<span class="zocial twitter"><a href="#">Share on Twitter/a></span>
```

And they are displayed on top of one another as opposed to side by side as I'd like them.

The CSS:

```
.zocial,
a.zocial {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-bottom-color: #333;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.08em 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4), inset 0 0 0.1em rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.08em 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4), inset 0 0 0.1em rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.08em 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4), inset 0 0 0.1em rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 100%/2.1 "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 .95em 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  white-space: nowrap;

  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  position: relative;

  -moz-border-radius: .3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: .3em;
  border-radius: .3em;
}

.zocial:before {
  content: "";
  border-right: 0.075em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  font: 120%/1.65 zocial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;

  -moz-box-shadow: 0.075em 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0.075em 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  box-shadow: 0.075em 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.25);

  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.zocial:active {
  outline: none; /* outline is visible on :focus */
}
```

Comment: They seem side by side http://jsfiddle.net/kYcfv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks fine to me you just didn't close your `a` tag properly

```
Share on Facebook/a>
Share on Twitter/a>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N7EZ4/)

Comment: Thanks @jmore009, unfortunetly the a tag was just for S.O so that can't be it, I'm using rails to do the linking so the linking should be fine. Not sure why they aren't appearing side-by-side.

Comment: Gotcha. check the fiddle though, its working fine for me on chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome also, it might be another div.class that is throwing it off.. I'll look into it, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!